# Path.GetFileName bug?

Tags: .net

Part of my .NET application needs to take an input string (representing a URI) and return only the filename (and extension if applicable).

Now `Path.GetFileName` does this perfectly fine for most paths, with the following exception: if the input string is an HTTP path that consists only of a domain name (e.g. example.com) and port number (e.g. 10210), `GetFileName` returns the port number.

In simple English: the input string is `http://example.com:10210`, which is a URI that links to an internet radio stream.
When `Path.GetFileName` is called with that value, the return value is `10210`.

Is this intended behavior? I can't recall any platform that separates path segments with colons. Shouldn't the return value be `String.Empty`?

**EDIT**

It seems like the clean solution would be a mashup between `Uri.LocalPath` and `System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.GetFileName`, but that implies re-targetting your project from a client profile to the full framework.

I think I'll just go with removing everything before (and including) the last forward-slash symbol. The separator never changes in my scenario anyway. Doing that gives me `example.com:10210` as the return value, which sort of makes sense for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [docs on the Path class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bdzys9w), it doesn't really appear that they intend you to use it with http or ftp or anything like that. All of the examples are around local file paths and network share paths.

Based on some other anecdotal info from around the web, [such as this article about Path.Combine](http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/06/08/pathcombine-for-urls/), I'm led to believe that you shouldn't use Path for HTTP.

Comment: Oh... well that's a shame. It does actually work for pretty much any sort of URI you can throw at it, except the ones I described.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure about this. This is my guess..

`Path` class is intended to use for Paths that have an underlying file system. (your HTTP request may not point to a file system. It could be simply a dynamically generated resource.)

You're supposed to use `Uri` class for URI parsing.

Answer (score 0):

`Path.VolumeSeparatorChar` (colon) is not part of the results in a call to `Path.GetInvalidPathChars`, which is what `Path.GetFileName` uses to validate the input is fine. Unfortunately it appears that this is expected behaviour.